# GetAsyncKeyState with held CTRL button and another "toggled" button not working as wanted

Tags: c++, windows, c++17, msdn

I got the following code for testing purposes:

```
bool test = false;
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F2) & 1) {
    test = !test;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

Now what I would like to happen is when I hold down the left control and then press F2 that the instructions are being properly handled.
The problem is that the condition turns to true if I hold LCTRL and then F2 or when I hold F2 and then press LCTRL or when I press LCTRL and then press F2 or when I press F2 and then LCTRL. So no matter which combination of which button to press I use the condition always turns out to be true.

I hope some of you people encountered this at some point and can help with some very much appreciated insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetAsyncKeyState` returns multiple things in its return value. The correct way to check if a key is down is: `bool lctrldown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) < 0;`

That being said, waiting for a user to press <kbd>F2</kbd> implies polling and polling is bad! If you only care about <kbd>F2</kbd> in your own window then you should use `TranslateAccelerator` in your message loop or handle `WM_KEYDOWN`.

For a global solution, use [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) or a [low-level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa).

In the case of `WM_KEYDOWN` or a hook, when you get notified about <kbd>F2</kbd> you should then check the state of the control key with `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: "*The correct way to check if a key is down is...*" - Alternatively: `bool lctrldown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) & 0x8000;`